# Ways of creating expected object for assert

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, tdd

Recently, I started to use TDD. It's really cool and fun but creating expected object for `assertEquals` is very boring and tedious.

At the moment I see only two way for that:

**Straightforward**
Creating object in code using million of setters. Using that approach greater part of tests is creating expected object. I think it's not very cool.

**Serialization**
Writing expected object for example in JSON and then serialize it in test. I can't find disadvantages of that way except possibility of inconsistent state between my beans and test files.

**EDIT**

**toString()** (*@Kilian Foth comment*)
Some kind of serialization, but I think it deserves attention. Define a strictly controlled toString() and then assert equality with a literal string rather than a second object.

**Configuring in DI container**(*inspired by @Spotted*)
I remembered about DI. Does anybody configure expected bean in DI (Spring XML for example) and then inject it to test method? Is it bad and unefficient approach or something normal?

Are there any other techniques/approaches or special tools that can accelerate that process?

Comment: I do json serialisation to files when i want to compare exact output. Sometiimes i also get the test to output the actual object to a file as well. makes it easy to update the sample when things change

Comment: [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0&list=PLD0011D00849E1B79&index=2) discuss about unit testing, object creation, DI, ... This may partially answer your question and help you to simplify your tests.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are specifically testing the `equals()` method of a class, there is usually no reason for a unit test to assert the equality of two objects. A unit test should test **one** behaviour and not **all** features of a code unit, whether that is a module, a class or even a method (a method with many possible inputs usually needs many unit tests and not just one).

Therefore, there is often no need to create such a "comparison object". If you're verifying that a transaction puts your customer in the correct status, obtain the customer and `assert` things about its status, not that it's exactly equal to another complex object that the test provides. That is almost certainly testing too much an in a very brittle way, since *any* change to the customer class might break the "status" test.

Comment: I agree with you. But in my practice I often meet scenarios when I need to check complex transformation or genaration from template and other things like that. I think in these cases most simple and maybe one possible solution is to check equals of objects. Am I wrong?

Comment: @vakoroteev If the entire purpose of an object is to represent the template for something, then yes, it can be useful to test all of its properties at once. In such cases I usually define a strictly controlled `toString()` and then assert equality with a literal string rather than a second object.

Comment: @KilianForth, ty. I added toString() way to question

Answer (score 0):

An other alternative I'd like to suggest is the following:

Instead of checking that the whole result object matches the expected value, write several asserts that check the important properties of the object.

Now, some people claim that you should only have 1 assert in a test. They are right that you should assert 1 thing, but that does not necessarily mean that you only have 1 assert.

Example: suppose you have a testcase that checks that after a bank transaction, some money moved. (Example in pseudo-code):

```
function testMoneyMovedAfterTransaction():
    account1 = setupFakeAccount(balance=300)
    account2 = setupFakeAccount(balance=600)
    performTransaction(from=account1, to=account2, amount=100)
    assertEquals(account1.balance, 200)
    assertEquals(account2.balance, 700)
```

See: two asserts, but I'm only asserting one thing: the money moved accounts, as requested.

Similarly, I might write a test for what happens when the balance is too low. That would be asserting that nothing happens to the balances, and you get an exception. That would take three asserts, but you're only asserting nothing changed.

*Edit*: if you're talking about 'templates' as in generated blobs of text: easiest might be to do a substring-search or regular-expression match against the generated text. For 'templates' as in generated data structures: an assert for individual fields might be the most robust.